# getting rid of the ending of the url

Tags: php, regex

I am using php and i want the part of the url without the /floor-plans/dsafasd
so i want 
something/whatever

instead of

something/whatever/floor-plans/dsafasd

Comment: Do you always know what you want to get rid of? Is there a pattern?

Comment: What is the replacement rule here?

Comment: i always want to get rid of /floor-plan and everything after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = preg_replace("#/floor-plan.*#i","",$url);
```

should do the trick then.

Comment: I think * is better than + if there's nothing after floor-plan

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to remove "floor-plans" you could use str_replace().

If it's always the 6th item in the URL, you could explode the url inton an array and then reassemble the pieces you'd like (removing the 5th item in this case since you start a 0 = "wiki")

If it's a regex thing, you'll need to provide more or a pattern to help someone build it...